# Atalho pela letra inicial OptionMenu no TKinter em Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Tenho um OptionMenu no TKinter em Python que é uma lista grande, quando aperto a letra G por exemplo ele não me direciona para os elementos com a letra G e também não permite a utilização de pageUp e pageDown. Existe um meio de fazer isso funcionar assim? Ou algum outro tipo de OptionMenu no Tkinter que permita essas funções? Usar o scroll do mouse para isso seria uma boa alternativa também.

Meu OptionMenu:

```
ent7 = tk.OptionMenu(janela,EntradaEnergia, *energias)
```

Answer (score 1):

O Tkinter, apesar de atender bem para as necessidades básicas, tem muito poucos desenvolvedores ativos, e as vezes a melhor documentação é olhar direto dentro do código fonte (além da documentação semi-oficial que está em http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)

Bom, fazendo essas duas coisas descobri que

1. não há suporte para barras de rolagem nos menus (OptionMenu inclusive)
2. Existe como configurar aceleradores para cada opção, mas não encontrei uma forma do acelerador de fato funcionar de forma direta.

Você pode tentar explorar os aceleradores - a partir do OptionMenu é possível recuperar um menu interno usando anotação de mapping. Você pode fazer: `menu_interno = ent7["menu"]` e vai ter um objeto menu que vai ter todos os métodos aqui:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm

Nesse ponto é possível configurar um "accelerator" para as entradas, por exemplo: `menu_interno.entryconfig(0, accelerator=energias[0][0])`, e a primeira letra da primeira opção na lista "energias" será exibida a direita da opção,no menu (0 é o índice da entrada). Mas ele só faz isso: o acelerador não funcionou para mim.

## Solução

é possível usar o `bind` normal do Tkinter para chamar um callback para uma tecla digitada quando o menu estiver aberto, e fazer esse callback setar a variável e ajustar o display do OptionButton "manualmente". Como a função para fazer isso vai precisar do OptionMenu, das opções e da variável inicial, é mais prático fazer a própria função criar o OptionMenu e configurar tudo isso:

```
import tkinter

def accelerated_menu(root, variable, *options, command=None):
    accelerators = {option[0]: option for option in options}

    menu = tkinter.OptionMenu(root, variable, *options, command=command)

    def callback(event):
        key = getattr(event, "char", None)
        if not key in accelerators:
            return
        value = accelerators[key]
        variable.set(value)
        menu["text"] = value
        if command:
            command(value)

    for index, option in enumerate(options):
        menu["menu"].entryconfig(index, accelerator=option[0])

    menu["menu"].bind("<Key>", callback)

    return menu
```

Basta usar a função acima, em vez de chamar o `OptionMenu` diretamente, que a primeira letra de cada opção será um atalho. Claro que isso não é o ideal, já que basicamente te limita a ter sempre uma letra diferente na primeira posição- e no caso de primeiras letras repetidas, as opções de cima são esquecidas e ficam valendo as últimas. Mas é fácil criar uma lógica com "if" para aceitar tuplas de dois itens, em vez de strings, nas opções, permitindo que você passe os atalhos explicitamente.

## Alternativa

O `OptionMenu` assim como alguns outros widgets, é construido em Python puro a partir de outros widgets mais primitivos (no caso, o "Menu" mesmo e um "MenuButton"). É possível construir uma classe extendendo um Widget de Tkinter que tenha não só os requisitos que você quer, mas seja ainda mais legal.

Eu sugeriria uma classe que contivesse um grid de botões, configurados sem relevo e sem borda, que aparecesse/desaparecesse num frame ao se clicar num botão em exibição permanente. Você teria controle completo do frame (portanto, podendo adicionar barra de rolagem, mostrar as opções em várias colunas), e dos botões (podendo configurar atalhos de teclado com "bind" de eventos).

Criar uma classe dessas vai exigir algumas horas de trabalho e não está no escopo deste site - mas é perfeitamente factível.